# Problem "/empty/" when create directory on pulseaudio

Tags: pulseaudio

I have problem with pulse audio on my user.log:

> pulseaudio[1836]: [autospawn] core-util.c: Failed to create secure
>   directory (/var/empty/.config/pulse)

I see "/empty/" I think is conf problem but how to configure that ?

Answer (score 1):

Your Pulseaudio is running as a user whose home directory is set as `/var/empty`. This is typically done for special application users created for privilege separation purposes or something similar. Such a user should probably not be running Pulseaudio at all.

Use `grep /var/empty /etc/passwd` to see if you can identify the user account that has its home set as `/var/empty`. Then find out the purpose of that account and either disable Pulseaudio from starting on that account, or disable regular logins to that account altogether if direct login is not required.